# Right-handed neutrinos Lagrangian and drawing Feynman diagrams from it

Tags: feynman-diagrams, neutrinos, dark-matter, beyond-the-standard-model, chirality

The Lagrangian for the right handed neutrino field is:
$$
L_{\nu} = y_{\alpha i} \bar{L_{\alpha}} H^{\dagger} N_{i} + m_{i} \bar{N^{c}_{i}N_{i}}
$$
With $ L_{\alpha} $ being the left-handed lepton doublets, $H$ being the Higgs and $N_{i}$ being the right handed neutrino field. I am required to draw Feynman diagrams leading to the annihilation of two right handed neutrinos into leptons, however from this Lagrangian it does not seem possible - there is no propagator term and the only interaction term is between 1 lepton, 1 RH neutrino and a Higgs boson?

Comment: The propagator depends on how you connect the vertices together, here you can connect two together at the higgs and so have a virtual higgs in a t-channel diagram to get two neutrinos to two leptons.

Comment: @Triatticus Could you elaborate please? I'm not quite sure what you mean - you can connect two of what together? In a t-channel process would that be annihilation? Is that not scattering?

Comment: Example: take any QED tree level diagram, cut it in half by cutting the virtual line, you get two separate QED vertexes because the diagrams are constructed by connecting vertexes as they are the interaction building blocks to make the diagrams.

Comment: Yes but QED vertices have the 2 fermion, 1 photon vertex so you could have two fermions annihilate into a photon which propagates before decaying into two fermions. In this right handed neutriono theory you have only a Higgs-Fermion-RH neutruno vertex right? so the only possible RH neutrino RH neutrino --> fermion fermion interaction is scattering of two RH neutrinos as you cannot have two RH neutrinos joined to the same vertex?

Comment: The higgs is it's own antiparticles, just take one vertex and the charge conjugate of the vertex, one has $\ell$ and $\bar{N}$ coupled to a higgs, the second can be $\bar{\ell}$ and $N$ couplied to a higgs. Join them into one diagram to make $N \bar{N}\to h \to \ell \bar{\ell}$ but as a t-channel diagram.